# Performance increase for an update statement

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, sql-execution-plan

I need to update all the columns in a table using the trimmed version of the same columns. Table has 130 columns and 5 million records. And the query is running more than 3 hours without any sign of completion.

```
Begin 
    UPDATE table
       SET column = TRIM(column)
     WHERE date = '01-01-21';
    .
     ..
      ..
    Commit;
End;
/
```

Kindly help in improving the performance of this query.
PS: none of the columns have any index.

Comment: Why do you keep the WHERE condition ?

Comment: My aim is to update the columns for a particular date. Without date filter, total no.of records to be updated would be huge..

Comment: But, you say : " _need to update **all** the columns_ " and " _none of the columns have any index_ "(including that _date_ column )

Comment: If you're planning to run for every single day separately... shouldn't you then create an index for the date?

Comment: Understood.. no need to update that date column.. rest needs to be updated with trimmed version of itself.

Comment: @JamesZ it's one time activity only.. not a repetitive process

Comment: You can also drop indexes. If you plan to run it day-by-date, an index makes a lot of sense. Or run the whole thing without a where criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PL/SQL but SQL:

```
update that_table set
  col1 = trim(col1),
  col2 = trim(col2),
  ...
  col130 = trim(col130)
where date_column = date '2021-01-01';
```

Column in `where` clause should - probably - only be indexed as you're filtering on it. If you're updating the whole table, you don't need `where` clause at all.

Also, if that column's datatype is `date`, then use date literal or `to_date` function with appropriate format model, i.e. don't *force* Oracle to implicitly convert string (that's `'01-01-21'` to date and spend some time doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would like to know how this would improve the performance over the one I have written?? Just for better understanding purpose, could you respond/explain?

Comment: Code you posted (at least, that's what I understood by looking at it) updates column-by-column in 130 separate UPDATE statements so you're accessing the same table 130 times, while my option does that in one run. Plus, implicit datatype conversion. Plus, index on DATE_COLUMN.

Comment: To increase the performance of the update, you need to remove the indexes on the fields that you update, because. when updating, the corresponding index changes and the overhead is very large. After updating the fields, you need to recreate the indexes that you previously deleted.

Comment: @Dmitry, there are no indexes on that table at all.